java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method crash in release aar build
`I have 2 branches

Main Branch(Production)
Stage Branch -> here I have created a separate feature module and added the below progaurd rules in the module for this issue and also annotated Data class with @Keep and created aar release build and integrated it with the Main branch

Problem
When I run or create the release build of main branch and launch the module by pressing on icon it crashes but It works fine in debug build.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/example/database/entity/content_leaderboard/EmployeeData; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.database.entity.content_leaderboard.EmployeeData' appears in /data/data/in.example.test.staging/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes19.dex)
at com.example.content_leaderboard.data.remote.dto.EmployeeDataDto.toEmployeeData(EmployeeDataDto.kt:41)
at com.example.content_leaderboard.data.remote.dto.PostDataDto.toPostData(PostDataDto.kt:86)
at com.example.content_leaderboard.data.repository.LeaderboardRepositoryImpl$getLeaderBoardDataRemote$2.invokeSuspend(LeaderboardRepositoryImpl.kt:41)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@fbfb7aa, Dispatchers.IO]

Solution I tried added proguard rules.
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.**
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
    static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}

-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{}
-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }

-keep class * extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase
-keep @androidx.room.Entity class *
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**

-keep public class com.example.database.entity.content_leaderboard.** { *; }
-keep public class com.example.content_leaderboard.data.remote.dto.** { *; }

Data class where crash is pointing
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class EmployeeDataDto(
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_EMPLOYEE_ID)
    val employeeID: Int,
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_EMPLOYEE_PROFILE_PICTURE_URL)
    val employeeProfilePictureURL: String?="",
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_RANKING)
    val ranking: String?="",
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_SUBTITLE)
    val subtitle: String?="",
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_TITLE)
    val title: String?="",
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_TOTAL_POINTS)
    val totalPoints: String?="",
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_NEXT_MILESTONE)
    val nextMilestone: String?="",
    @SerializedName(JsonKeys.KEY_NEXT_MILESTONE_POINTS)
    val nextMilestonePoints: String?=""
): Parcelable{
    
    fun toEmployeeData(): EmployeeData {
        return EmployeeData(      ===> **Line no 41**
            employeeID = employeeID,
            employeeProfilePictureURL = employeeProfilePictureURL,
            ranking = ranking,
            title = title,
            totalPoints = totalPoints,
            nextMilestone = nextMilestone,
            nextMilestonePoints = nextMilestonePoints
        )
    }

}

